# How to split a sting by regex pattern and also capture pattern content?

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a text that contains numbers

```
text = "bla bla 1 bla bla bla 142 bla bla (234.22)"
```

and want to add a `'\n'` before and after each number.

```
> "bla bla \n1\n bla bla bla \n142\n bla bla (234.22)"
```

The following function gives me the sub strings, but it throws away the pattern, i.e. the numbers. What is the best way to replace a pattern with something that contains the pattern in python?

```
re.split(' [0123456789]+ ', text)
```

Comment: use `re.sub` instead of `re.split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
s = re.sub(r' \d+ ', '\n\\g<0>\n', s)
```

See the  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/081OkV/1).

To replace only standalone numbers as whole words use

```
s = re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', '\n\\g<0>\n', s)
```

If you want to match the numbers enclosed with whitespaces only use either of

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', '\n\\g<0>\n', s) # also at the start/end of string
re.sub(r'(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)', '\n\\g<0>\n', s) # only between whitespaces
```

Actually, the replacement can be specified as `'\n\g<0>\n'`, as `\g` is an undefined escape sequence and the backslash will be treated as literal char in this case and will be preserved in the resulting string to form the regex backreference construct.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/KAhtZj):

```
import re
s = "bla bla 1 bla bla bla 142 bla bla"
s = re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', '\n\\g<0>\n', s)
print(s) # => bla bla \n1\n bla bla bla \n142\n bla bla
```

Comment: Almost, I needed to include the blanks around the numbers and it does what I needed. Thanks! `re.sub(r' \b\d+\b ', '\n\\g<0>\n', text)`

Comment: @Sören Then remove the `\b` altogether

Comment: Perfect! 7 more to go

Answer (score 2):

Try this code!! This might help!

```
import re
text = "bla bla 1 bla bla bla 142 bla bla"
replaced = re.sub('([0-9]+)', r'\n\1\n',text)
print(replaced)

Output:  'bla bla \n1\n bla bla bla \n142\n bla bla'
```